# Ruby and ActiveMQ. AMQ339016: Error creating subscription Stomp::Error::BrokerException

Tags: ruby, activemq-classic

I am running a simple Ruby program to produce and consume ActiveMQ Stomp messages. I keep on getting this error.

```
    /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/stomp-1.3.4/lib/stomp/client.rb:132:in `join': AMQ339016: Error creating subscription f7b282396a9bef2da1ccd42d16dc511758234113 (Stomp::Error::BrokerException)
    from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/stomp-1.3.4/lib/stomp/client.rb:132:in `join'
    from consumer.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

I made sure ActiveMQ is up and from I can tell it is not necessary to configure the xml config files since ActiveMQ is supposed to support Stomp out of the box. My program looks like this:

```
    require 'rubygems'
    require 'stomp'

    client = Stomp::Client.open "stomp://localhost:61613"
    client.subscribe "/queue/myqueue" do |message|
    puts "received: #{message.body} on #{message.headers['destination']}"
    end
    client.join
    client.close
    puts "completed process"
```

The full example code can be found here:

http://arhipov.blogspot.com/2009/05/activemq-ruby-stomp-transport.html

Comment: I have been able to find one workaround. The example I found is quite old. After downgrading my ActiveMQ from Version 6 to Version 4.1.2 the problem disappeared. I have not tried any Version 5.x yet. The setup of configuration files has changed significantly from Version 4.1.2 to Version 6. It still would be nice how to implement this in the latest version of ActiveMQ